# How to copy file from smb server

Tags: ssh, smb

I have an air quality monitor which has a smb URL smb://192.168.0.131 and I would like to copy files stored on it but I cannot seem be able to ssh into it using sudo ssh username@192.168.0.131. It keeps saying incorrect password. What search terms would you use to do something like this?

## Edit from comment

I'm on Mac but I'm going to see if I can figure out the equivalent commands from Rinzwind's answer.

Comment: SSH is not SMB.  You are not going to be able to SSH into an SMB share/system if it's not exposing SSH.  SMB is also Microsoft compatible shares, so I don't know why you're trying to SSH to the box.  You need to use the SMB protocol to connect to the device to copy files on the share to your system.  This does NOT mean you'll be able to get the system files for the monitor though, only what it puts in the SMB shares

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1373335/edit) and add which version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using? Are you using the server or the desktop?

Comment: @user68186 I'm on Mac but I'm going to see if I can figure out the equivalent commands from Rinzwind's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ssh (secure shell) is not smb (Samba)
- you list 2 different IPs for smd and ssh. 1 will be wrong.

You can mount samba with `cifs-utils` so if not installed install it with ...

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Create a permanent mount point and mount the share:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/air_quality_monitor
sudo mount -t cifs -o "domain=DOMAIN,username=USER,password=PASSWORD,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0" //IP /mnt/air_quality_monitor
```

- All the words in capitals need to be changed to what you need.
- `sec` is the security mode and determines how passwords are encrypted between server and client ( even if you don't require passwords ). `ntlm` used to be the default so that might work. If not omit it or check `man mount.cifs` for other supported models.
- `vers=1.0` might need to be changed to a supported version. You can also try it without this option.
- `domain`might not be needed too; if you do not have one remove `domain=DOMAIN,` from the options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated!